# Can I give unprivileged users access to journalctl logs for specific units?

Tags: systemd

I have a custom Systemd service (`my.service`) running a binary with unprivileged user `serv`.

I can watch logs for that service with `journalctl -fu my.service` as I am in the `systemd-journal` group.

Can I give permissions to user `joe` so that they can run `journalctl -fu my.service` without adding `joe` to `systemd-journal`?

Currently, if `joe` runs `journalctl -fu my.service`, they get:

```
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
```

I want `joe` to not be able to see all system logs. I only want to enable seeing specific units' logs.

Of course I could add `joe` to `systemd-journal` group but that would give them access to all logs.

I could also add a specific `sudo` exception for `joe` so that they could run `sudo journalctl -fu my.service` but that only works for one set of flags. There are other flags to `journalctl` that `joe` might want to use. Maybe they want to watch all logs that they're allowed to see at once. Maybe they have some custom filtering they want to add.

Is there a way to do this with `journalctl` (or other) configuration that I'm not seeing?

Comment: You could try [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/841099/systemd-grant-an-unprivileged-user-permission-to-alter-one-specific-service), or another thing I could think of is add a service to copy the logs to a shared directory.

Comment: @644 that doesn't work for me. This could work if only `joe` needed access but I really want to allow all users in a group to access the logs. I do also want those users to be able to start/stop the service. Fortunately that works well enough with `sudo` since there aren't many options.

Comment: In that case you could use regex for the command line arguments in the sudoers file, see https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html#Wildcards

Comment: @644 I was not aware of regex for sudoers file. That could work. Seems like an anti-pattern to me though. Too many possibilities for mistakes in the regex allowing for possible unintentional privilege escalation.

Comment: Well it's not technically regex, more like wildcard matching, and I'm unsure if it supports flags. Probably best to just write a rule for each command option.